# How can I create a vbs file by batch without losing those lines?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, escaping

Everytime I tries to create a vbs file by batch , some lines are missing in the vbs file

```
@echo off
echo Function RunAsAdmin() >> 2.vbs
echo If WScript.Arguments.length = 0 Then >> 2.vbs
echo CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & _ >> 2.vbs
echo WScript.ScriptFullName & """" & "RunAsAdministrator""",,"runas", 1 >> 2.vbs
echo WScript.Quit >> 2.vbs
echo End If >> test.vbs
```

What do i need to keep these 2 lines when making a vbs file by batch?

```
echo CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & _ >> 2.vbs
echo WScript.ScriptFullName & """" & "RunAsAdministrator""",,"runas", 1 >> 2.vbs`
```

Comment: Try to use `"` around the text. I think it is because you use specual characters/keywords. You can escape characters using `^`.

Comment: The ampersand is a special character and must be escaped with a carrot.

Comment: a side note, any redirection opens and closes the file, but `>"%outfile%" ( ...all echo here... )` will open the file, proccess all within the parenthesized block, and close the file. this will speed up your code. btw, `(...) >"%outfile%"` is the same.

Comment: Although in the case of the latter, you'd need to also escape the nested internal closing parentheses too!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative method that avoids the necessity of escaping:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_VBS_FILE=%~dp02.vbs"

rem // Write to given output file:
> "%_VBS_FILE%" (
    rem // Read all lines from this batch script that begin with `::::`:
    for /F "delims=" %%V in ('findstr "^::::" "%~f0"') do (
        rem // Store current line string:
        set "VBS_LINE=%%V"
        rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid loss of `!`:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Return current line string with preceding `::::` removed:
        echo(!VBS_LINE:*::::=!
        endlocal
    )
)
endlocal
exit /B

::This is the embedded VBS code section with each line preceded by `::::`:
::::Function RunAsAdmin()
::::If WScript.Arguments.length = 0 Then
::::    CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & _
::::        WScript.ScriptFullName & """" & "RunAsAdministrator""", , "runas", 1
::::    WScript.Quit
::::End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this How to [Escape Characters](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php) in batch file.

```bat
@echo off
Title Generate VBS File from batch script
Set "VBSFile=%~dpn0.vbs"
Call :Generate_VBS_File
Pause & Exit
REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Generate_VBS_File
>"%VBSFile%" ( 
    echo    Function RunAsAdmin(^)
    echo    If WScript.Arguments.length = 0 Then
    echo        CreateObject("Shell.Application"^).ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" ^& _
    echo        WScript.ScriptFullName ^& """" ^& "RunAsAdministrator""",,"runas", 1
    echo        WScript.Quit
    echo    End If
    echo    End Function
)
Exit /B
REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Hackoo, you don't need to escape any opening parentheses, just the ampersands, _as those are special characters_, and the internal closing parentheses, _to prevent the early closure of your parenthesized block_.

Comment: @Compo You are right ! , so, i edit my answer refer to your remark ! Thank you !

Comment: Escaping the opening parentheses is not necessary but does not harm either; I usually escape them for the sake of code readability. Anyway, you will need `exit /B` before `:Generate_VBS_File` to avoid writing the file twice…

Comment: Whilst it may do no harm to the code @aschipfl, it certainly harms the basic understanding of what must be escaped, _(which is technically what this answer is about)_. I would probably add an `Exit` or `GoTo :EOF` in place of the `pause` too though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape few special characters while echoing into files. The below code will do the trick for you.

```
echo CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^).ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" ^& ^_ >>2.vbs
echo WScript.ScriptFullName ^& """" ^& "RunAsAdministrator""",,"runas",1 >>2.vbs
```

For example Use ^ to print the spcial characters like _,&. (**Note:** ^&-> will print &)

check the below link to know more about batch-escape characters.

https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php