# How do i make the vbs file to work properly?

Tags: batch-file

When i tried to create a vbs file with batch, this line doesn't show in the vbs file

`echo WScript.Sleep 2000 : Objshell.Run "taskkill /f /im cmd.exe", 0 >> 2.vbs`

What do i need to escape or something to make the vbs file runnable ?
Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this [Escape Characters in Batch](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate here ==> [How can I create a vbs file by batch without losing those lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62165309/how-can-i-create-a-vbs-file-by-batch-without-losing-those-lines?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Absolutely nothing @Stub, the line you've provided works exactly as intended, without issue. The file `2.vbs` will receive the line `WScript.Sleep 2000 : Objshell.Run "taskkill /f /im cmd.exe", 0 `. Your issue is probably with the other lines you've output to `2.vbs`, or if you haven't sent any others, that you've not done so.

Comment: Oh thank you! It really worked!

Comment: *N. B.:* The _space_ in front of `>>` is going to be written to the file too; although it does not harm in this situation, you may want to change the approach to `>> 2.vbs echo ...` to avoid such…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a new batch code to make life easier for users in order to integrate some vbs files that will be generated automatically with a batch file when we execute it.
This batch code is based on search and replace using Regex with vbscript.
So, the user can just drag and drop a vbscript over this batch script. And voila !

```bat
@echo off
Title Vbs2Bat Intergration using Regex with vbscript by Hackoo 2020
Set "InputFile=%~1"
If ["%InputFile%"] EQU [""] Goto :Help
Set "TempFile=%Temp%\%~n1.tmp"
Set "OutPutFile=%~dpn1_.txt"
Call :Search_Replace "%InputFile%" "%TempFile%"
REM ------------------------Generate the formatted file------------------------------
> "%OutPutFile%" ( 
    echo @echo off
    echo Call :Generate_VBS_File
    echo Call :Execute_VBS_File
    echo REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    echo :Generate_VBS_File
    echo ^>"%%tmp%%\%%~n0.vbs" ( 
)
>> "%OutPutFile%" (@for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('Type "%TempFile%"') do echo. echo    %%a)
>> "%OutPutFile%" (
    echo ^)
    echo Exit /B
    echo REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    echo :Execute_VBS_File
    echo cscript //nologo "%%tmp%%\%%~n0.vbs"
    echo If Exist "%%tmp%%\%%~n0.vbs" Del "%%tmp%%\%%~n0.vbs"
    echo Exit /B
    echo REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
)
REM ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
If Exist "%TempFile%" Del "%TempFile%"
If Exist "%OutPutFile%" Start "" "%OutPutFile%" & Exit
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Search_Replace <InputFile> <OutPutFile>
(
    echo WScript.StdOut.WriteLine Search_Replace(Data^)
    echo Function Search_Replace(Data^)
    echo Dim strPattern, strReplace, strResult,oRegExp
    echo Data = "%~1" 
    echo Data = WScript.StdIn.ReadAll
    echo Set oRegExp = New RegExp
    echo oRegExp.Global = True 
    echo oRegExp.Multiline = True 
    echo oRegExp.IgnoreCase = True 
    echo strPattern1 = "[)&<|>]"
    echo oRegExp.Pattern = strPattern1
    echo strReplace1 = "^$+"
    echo strResult1 = oRegExp.Replace(Data,strReplace1^)
    echo strPattern2 = "[%%]"
    echo oRegExp.Pattern = strPattern2
    echo strReplace2 = "%%$+"
    echo strResult2 = oRegExp.Replace(strResult1,strReplace2^)
    echo Search_Replace = strResult2
    echo End Function
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
cscript //nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" < "%~1" > "%~2"
If Exist "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" Del "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
Exit /B
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Help
Mode 70,4 & Color 0C
echo(
echo      You should drag and drop a VBS file over, 
echo      this script "%~nx0" to be converted !
Timeout /T 10 /NoBreak>nul
Exit
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```